# Setting model value on page load

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model

Is there a way to set the models value on a page load. Because i need it to populate a schema with model values. and i tried a document.ready ajax call to get the model but it tells me that the model has no value before the ajax call even happens.

here is the code and you can see how im trying to populate the schema but it wont hit the functions

```
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    <script>      
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Team/Calendar/PopulateCalendar/',
                type: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
            });
        });
        $(function () {


            $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
                date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
                startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"),
                height: 600,
                views: [
                "day",
                    { type: "week", selected: true },
                    "month",
                    "agenda"
                ],
                timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                dataSource: {
                    batch: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/Team/Calendar/PopulateCalendar/",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        update: {
                            url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/tasks/update",
                            dataType: "jsonp"
                        },
                        create: {
                            url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/tasks/create",
                            dataType: "jsonp"
                        },
                        destroy: {
                            url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/tasks/destroy",
                            dataType: "jsonp"
                        },
                        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {

                            id: "taskId",
                            fields: {
                                taskId: { from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar=> calendar.TaskId)", type: "number" },
                                title: { from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar=> calendar.Title)", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                                start: { type: "date", from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar => calendar.Start)" },
                                end: { type: "date", from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar => calendar.End)" },
                                startTimezone: { from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar => calendar.StartTimezone)" },
                                endTimezone: { from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar => calendar.EndTimezone)" },
                                description: { from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar => calendar.Description)" },
                                recurrenceId: { from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar => calendar.RecurrenceId)" },
                                recurrenceRule: { from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar => calendar.RecurrenceRule)" },
                                recurrenceException: { from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar => calendar.RecurrenceException)" },
                                ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },
                                isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "@Model.CalendarItems.Select(calendar => calendar.IsAllDay)" }

                            }
                        }

                    },
                    filter: {
                        logic: "or",
                        filters: [
                            { field: "ownerId", operator: "eq", value: 1 },
                            { field: "ownerId", operator: "eq", value: 2 }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                resources: [
                    {
                        field: "ownerId",
                        title: "Owner",
                        dataSource: [
                            { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                            { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                            { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: Add a `.First()`, `.Single()`, or `.FirstOrDefault()` after your `.Select(...)`.  Currently, you're getting back a list of values rather than a single value.

Comment: 2nd: Look at your generated HTML.  It should provide clues as well.  If possible, post some of the important parts here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using ASPNET MVC with Razor, you should be able to set your model via Scriplet into the javascript.